# "IndexError" while slicing Numpy array with the built-in slice object

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow-datasets

I have an internal function in my Tensorflow data import pipeline where i am trying to apply anisotropic diffusion. I am currently stuck with an `IndexError: only integers, slices (":"), ellipsis ("..."), numpy.newaxis ("None") and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` and i can't understand the actual problem. The situation is the following:

```
deltas = [np.zeros(out.shape) for _ in range(out.shape.rank)]

    for _ in range(niter):
        for i in range(out.shape.rank):
            slicer =[slice(None, -1) if j == i else slice(None) for j in range(out.shape.rank)]
            deltas[i][slicer] = tf.experimental.numpy.diff(out, axis=i)
```

'out' is a 3D tf.Tensor with shape [224, 224, 1];

I've already tried different solutions like using tuples and numpy.s_ instead of the slice function with no luck. For the sake of clarity, this piece of code is inside a function called by a lambda inside tf.Dataset.map().
The expected output would be to be able to access the correct slice.

The full error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leo/Documents/repos/ChestXRayEnsembling/ChestXRAY/multidecoder/train_script.py", line 83, in <module>
    ds_d = dlo.XRayDatasetFromDirs(
  File "/Users/leo/Documents/repos/ChestXRayEnsembling/ChestXRAY/multidecoder/myDataLoaders.py", line 236, in XRayDatasetFromDirs
    ds = ds.map(lambda *args: (f(args[0], **kwargs), *args[1:]),
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2296, in map
    return ParallelMapDataset(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 5540, in __init__
    self._map_func = structured_function.StructuredFunctionWrapper(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py", line 263, in __init__
    self._function = fn_factory()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py", line 226, in get_concrete_function
    concrete_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py", line 192, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    concrete_function, _ = self._maybe_define_concrete_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py", line 157, in _maybe_define_concrete_function
    return self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py", line 360, in _maybe_define_function
    concrete_function = self._create_concrete_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compiler.py", line 284, in _create_concrete_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1283, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py", line 240, in wrapped_fn
    ret = wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py", line 171, in wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(self._func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 692, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.autograph.impl.api.StagingError: in user code:

    File "/Users/leo/Documents/repos/ChestXRayEnsembling/ChestXRAY/multidecoder/myDataLoaders.py", line 236, in None  *
        lambda *args: (f(args[0], **kwargs), *args[1:])
    File "/Users/leo/Documents/repos/ChestXRayEnsembling/ChestXRAY/multidecoder/myPreprocessing.py", line 413, in addChannelAnisotropicDiffusion  *
        diff = anisotropic_diffusion_tf(tf.expand_dims(img[:, :, 0], axis=-1), **kwargs)
    File "/Users/leo/Documents/repos/ChestXRayEnsembling/ChestXRAY/multidecoder/myPreprocessing.py", line 386, in anisotropic_diffusion_tf  *
        deltas[i][slicer] = tf.experimental.numpy.diff(out, axis=i)

    IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Full error message please.  And if possible, identify the `index` that giving the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj full error message added. the 'slicer' variable, which stores the slice object, seems to be the problem. Or, better, the fact that it is a 'list', because if i use, for instance, 'slicer[0]' it returns me a slice of the array.

Comment: Does `tuple(slicer)` work instead?

Comment: @MegaIng That actually works! I didn't try before because I already tried to create a tuple directly instead of a list and it yielded the same output, but this seems to do the job. What puzzles me though, is that I'm basically rewriting the `anisotropic_diffusion` function from the `medpy` library, and the original passage is exactly like that, so I really have no idea of what might be the issue...

Comment: It could be that newer numpy versions are pickier about the use of list versus tuple indexing arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MegaIng in the comment, `tuple(slicer)` solves the issue. The cause of the problem remains unclear though.